# watchOS 10 Beta - WKInterfaceController title alignment

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, titlebar, beta, wkinterfacecontroller

In our existing watchOS application developed in Objective-C (not SwiftUI), we used to set the *title* property (WKInterfaceController class) of each screen of the application (in Interface Builder or in the Objective-C code).

The title was displayed on the top left corner (while the time was displayed on the top right corner) => The two information were on the same line, which left a large part of the screen for the interface without a need for scrolling

We have built the application for watchOS 10 (with watchOS 10 Beta 7 SDK) and tested it on watch OS10 Beta 7 on an Apple Watch => the title is displayed on the right, behind the time => It uses two lines and the interface available for the application screens is much reduced.

Is there any solution to set the alignment of the title to the left in order to make it appear on the same line as the time, as on watchOS 9?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Best regards.

Comment: Hey @geolives. Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately we had to redesign the interface to adapt to these changes

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced this same issue with Xcode 15.1 watchOS 10. All the titles of WKInterfaceControllers are on the right side.
This is an Xcode issue. Run the smartwatch target on Xcode 14, and watchOS 10.

This issue will work fine.

Happy Coding.